# PLSQL to Hive Query Function Conversation

Tags: hive, hiveql

We are trying to migrate greenplum(postgresql) to hive and below plsql query needs to convert into hiveSQL. kindly do the help me.

Greenplum function query statement .

```
select extract(days from ((date_trunc('MONTH', column1::date) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::date)))::dec,2)::numeric daily;

select extract(year from column1)::character varying;

select extract(month from column2)::character varying;
```

> Note : extract, days from not available in hive. please help us.

We needs to convert HiveSQL.

Answer (score 0):

`extract` is available in hive 2.2 and higher.
You can see output of below sql.

```
select extract(day from current_date) dy,extract(month from current_date) mon, 
extract(year from current_date) yr
```

[image]

Now to answer to your query,

select extract(days from ((date_trunc('MONTH', column1::date) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::date)))::dec,2)::numeric daily;

- I think this is giving last day of month. You can use
  `extract(day from last_day(column1))`

select extract(year from column1)::character varying;

- You can use `cast ( extract(year from column1) as string)`

Pls note hive is very sensitive to data type, i assumed column as datetime in both scenario.

Comment: cast(extract(day from (cast(date_add(add_months(trunc(cast('2021-03-16'as date),'MM'),1),-1) as date))) as decimal) as bigint) daily_tgt -- this is not working

Comment: hi we are using 2.1.1-cdh6.3.2 version of hive, kindly help us.

Comment: some cast seems unnecessary. can you pls tell me the logic and an example?

Comment: i tried but needs to validate please check this query is correct ?  select extract(days from ((date_trunc('MONTH', column1::date) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::date)))::dec,2)::numeric daily; ====>>> cast(day(date_add(add_months(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast('2021-02-12' as date),'yyyy-MM'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),1), -1)) as int) daily_tgt